# Nested Attributes not working with Simple_form, Decent_exposure, Strong_parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using Simple_form with Decent_exposure, Strong_parameters I have the following setup and I can post to households but nothing gets posted to neighbors

model

```
class Household < ActiveRecord::Base
 include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

has_many :neighbors
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :neighbors
```

view

```
= simple_nested_form_for household do |f|
  = f.input :household_name
  = f.simple_fields_for :neighbor, Neighbor.new do |neighbor_form|
  = neighbor_form.input :first_name
  = neighbor_form.input :middle_name
  = neighbor_form.input :last_name
  = neighbor_form.input :address

  = f.button :submit
```

Based on the following from my log it looks like the form is working but it is not saving to neighbors the nested model - I have tried both simple_fields_for :neighbor do and simple_fields_for :neighbor, Neighbor.new do hoping that creating a new neighbor would help but it doesn't.

```
Parameters:{"utf8"=>"✓",
authenticity_token"=>"cVTteqPFa0JMoFi/ys0wAmNIQghubADv5lbPBr6hyq0=",
"household"=>  {"household_name"=>"Deew", "neighbor"=>{"first_name"=>"Bill",
"middle_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"Ew", "street"=>"we"}}, "commit"=>"Create Household"}
(0.1ms)  begin transactionSQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "households" ("created_at",
"household_name", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) 
[["created_at", Sun, 03 Feb 2013 03:02:56 UTC +00:00], ["household_name", "Deew"], 
["name", nil], ["updated_at", Sun, 03 Feb 2013 03:02:56 UTC +00:00]](0.8ms) 
commit transaction
```

Comment: Funny. This was one of the first things that came up when I tried googling your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you include neighbors_attributes in the allowable parameters.